# How to Make a Game Like Cut the Rope using vrope class?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

How to Make a Game Like Cut the Rope using vrope class ???

my game is on cocos2d for iphone >> cut the rope

Comment: Post some screenshot of what you trying to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this tutorial for this game

In this tutorial series, you’ll build a cool Cut the Rope-type game from scratch using Cocos2D and Box2D.

[CutThe Rope Part -1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14793/how-to-make-a-game-like-cut-the-rope-part-1)

[CutThe Rope Part -2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14812/how-to-make-a-game-like-cut-the-rope-part-2)

Comment: thanks .its one of the finest tutorials so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the tutorial over at Ray Wenderlich's site that covers this: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14793/how-to-make-a-game-like-cut-the-rope-part-1

Comment: thanks buddy brandon lassiter